# Kedro using wrong conda environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, kedro

I have created a conda environment called `Foo`. After activating this environment I installed Kedro with `pip`, since `conda` was giving me a conflict. Even though I'm inside the `Foo` environment, when I run:

```
kedro jupyter lab
```

It picks up the modules from my `base` environment, not the `Foo` environment. Any idea, why this is happening, and how I can change what modules my notebook detect?

**Edit**

By mangling with my code I found out that on the `\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\kedro_project\kernel.json` it was calling the python from the base environment, not the `Foo` environment. I changed it manually, but is there a mode automatic way of setting the `\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\kedro_project\kernel.json` to use the current environment I'm on?

Comment: Have you installed packages with `pip install --user`? Conda does not block the user site by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom Kedro kernel spec is a feature that I recently added to Kedro. When you run `kedro jupyter lab/notebook` it should automatically pick up on the conda environment without you needing to manually edit the kernel.json file. I tested this myself to check that it worked so I'm very interested in understanding what's going on here!

The function [`_create_kernel`](https://github.com/kedro-org/kedro/blob/58c57c384f5257b998edebb99d94bff46574ae1e/kedro/framework/cli/jupyter.py#L99) is what makes the the Kedro kernel spec. The docstring for that explains what's going on, but in short we delegate to [`ipykernel.kernelspec.install`](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/d02f4371348187c3e5e87a46388bbef92615c110/ipykernel/kernelspec.py#L92). This generates a kernelspec that points towards the Python path given by `sys.executable` (see [`make_ipkernel_cmd`](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/d02f4371348187c3e5e87a46388bbef92615c110/ipykernel/kernelspec.py#L27)). In theory this should already point towards the correct Python path, which takes account of the conda environment.

It's worth checking `which kedro` to see which conda environment that points to, and if we need to debug further then please do raise an issue on our [Github repo](https://github.com/kedro-org/kedro). I'd definitely like to get to the bottom of this and understand where the problem is.

P.S. you can also do a plain `jupyter lab/notebook` to launch a kernel with the right conda environment and then run `%load_ext kedro.extras.extensions.ipython` in the first cell. This is basically equivalent to using the Kedro kernelspec, which loads the Kedro IPython extension automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a problem with jupyter. I'd suggest trying to run jupyter notebook and understand if it is down to kedro or jupyter.

I remember facing something similar due to some jupyter problem but don't remember how I fixed it. I remember trying some solutions from
[this issue](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/270) on jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

Try do pip install jupyterlab in your foo enviornment, Jupyter Kernel is a different concept and acts weird sometimes.